# How to shift errobars along x-axis in ggplot2 when subsetting data?

Tags: r, graph, graphics, ggplot2

Here is some dummy data

```
set.seed(3)
d = data.frame(y = rnorm(120), x =rep(letters[5:7],40), category = rep(LETTERS[1:2],each=60))
```

I would like to display error bars for the mean for all of the data (in black) and only for `category=="B"` (in blue).

I tried

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x,y=y)) + stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data=mean_se) 
+ stat_summary(data=subset(d,category=="B"), geom = "errorbar", 
fun.data=mean_se, color="blue")
```

[image]

But the overlap of errorbars is unpleasant. So I tried

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=x,y=y)) + stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data=mean_se) 
+ stat_summary(aes(colour=category), geom = "errorbar", fun.data=mean_se,
 position=position_dodge(0.5)) + scale_colour_manual(values=c(rgb(1,1,1,alpha=0), "blue"))
```

[image]

but the width of the errorbars is automatically reduced in the blue case and the average position between the blue and black line does not match up with the label.

What is the best solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't use `stat_summary`. Instead, I calculated the mean and standard error for aggregated data and data only including category B. Then, I can use those values to create the plot. However, I found out that my error bar is different from what you showed.

This is my attempt to the question:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(3)
d <- data.frame(y=rnorm(120), x=rep(letters[5:7], 40),
                category=rep(LETTERS[1:2], each=60))

# Calculate the mean and standard error for each group
df_B <- d %>% filter(category == "B") %>% group_by(x) %>%
            summarise(mu=mean(y), se=sqrt(var(y)/length(y)))
df_all <- d %>% group_by(x) %>% summarise(mu=mean(y), se=sqrt(var(y)/length(y)))

df <- rbind(df_B, df_all)
df$category <- rep(c("B", "All"), each=3)


ggplot(df, aes(x=x, ymin=mu - se, ymax=mu + se, color=category, width=0.5)) +
  geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(width=0.6)) +
  scale_color_manual(breaks=c("All", "B"), values=c("black", "blue"))
```

[image]